# PHP preg_replace limit not working?

Tags: php, preg-replace, limits

I have a file that contains several colors as hexadecimals (i.e. #000 or #ffffff) and I'm trying to replace each of them with `@varN` where N is a number that increments with each replacement done. I believed my code does that, but `$count` always returns 196 after doing the placement even though I put the limit to 1 so count should never goes past 1. This results an endless loop. Why isn't it the limit working and what I can do to get the desired output?

```
$list = file($filepath.$file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$pattern = "/#((([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){6})|(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}))/";
$replaceVar = "@var";
$replaceNum = 0;
$count = 1;
while($count != 0){ //never ends
    $replacement = $replaceVar.$replaceNum;
    $output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$list,1,$count);
    $replaceNum++;
    echo $replaceNum." ".$count."\n"; //returns $replaceNum and 196
}
file_put_contents($filepath.'/new'.$file,$output,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

Example input file:

> #000000
>   
>   #111111
>   
>   #123456
>   
>   #abcdef
>   
>   #123
>   
>   #abc

Example output file:

> @var1
>   @var2
>   @var3
>   @var4
>   @var5
>   @var6

Comment: `file` put all contents to an array, you'd better use `file_get_contents`, here your `$count` wouldn't decrease so it's normal to have an infinite loop and what is `$count`?

Comment: `file_get_contents` gives me a string though, meaning I would have to some how turn the string back into a file with all the newlines in the right spot. I understand that `$count` is the number of times a replacement has been done to my `$list`. And with `$limit = 1`, `$count` should never go above 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the good function to do that for several reasons, I suggest you to use preg_replace_callback instead. Example:

```
$source = file_get_contents($yourfile);

$pattern = '~#[[:xdigit:]]{3}(?:[[:xdigit:]]{3})?~';
$count = 0;

$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                       function ($m) use (&$count) { return '@var' . ++$count; },
                                $source);
```

Comment: It works, however your regex gave me some unexpected results.

Comment: @user2361174: What kind of unexpected results?

Comment: @user2361174: Sorry my mistake! It is not `[:alnum:]` but `[:xdigit:]` for hex numbers!

Answer (score 1):

You are always replacing on `$list`, but writing the result of the replacement to `$output`:

```
$output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$list,1,$count);
```

This means, your `$list` will ALWAYS contain `1` match, when it starts with `1` - its never modified. Therefore your while will run without an end. You have to REPLACE it inside the same string you are scanning for more hits:

```
$list = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$list,1,$count);
```

now - at one point - `$count` should become zero, and `$list` contain no more unwanted matches.

Comment: The loop stopped, but it would always used `@var0` as the replacement.